# How to do size validation of values for columns before inserting data into table in sql for DB2?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, db2

I need to check whether the value is with proper size to be inserted into a table for particular column before actual insertion of data into table.

e.g.,

Suppose, I have a table 'MyTable' with column 'MYSMALLINT' of SMALLINT type in DB2,

If I try to insert the value as,

```
insert into MyTable(MYSMALLINT) values(12222222222222222222222222222225552);
```

I will get below error, after executing the above query:

***Message: The numeric literal "12222222222222222222222222222225552" is not valid because its value is out of range.***

Here, I need to check the size of value **before** inserting the data into table in Java/JDBC for a column with any data type(CHAR,VARCHAR,INT,BIGINT,TINYINT,DOUBLE,FLOAT,DECIMAL,REAL,...).

Comment: Why not just try to insert and if there is an exception, handle it accordingly?

Comment: If I am doing the batch operation, it fails at 99th record of 100 records, need to rollback that data right?, so I do not want the overhead of inserting/roll-backing

Comment: @Manikanta_AC You don't need to rollback for such an exception. If you commit, then records 1-98 will be committed and record 99 simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @Linger Correct, but in my case, want to rollback all data, if atleast one record insertion fails.

Comment: Is it really hard for your app to test whether 1222222222222222 > 32768 or whether a string is longer than a column's defined length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into MyTable(MYSMALLINT) values(?);"
for(Integer value:values){
   try{
      statement.setInt(1,value);
      statement.addBatch();
   }catch(SQLException e){
      System.err.println("Invalid value: " + e.getMessage());
      throw e;
   }
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Sure, it is correct answer. But could you please share me any otherway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the before value in a trigger if it is valid for your requirements. The way you validate the value can a UDF, in that way you can test it outside the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just map the column to the correct Java primitive.

Smallint is equivalent to a "short" in Java so if you defined your host variable as a short the compiler would detect any errors at compile time.

```
insert into MyTable(MYSMALLINT) values(12222222222222222222222222222225552S);
```

would be spat out by your java compiler.